# How to count the number of requests for each method

Tags: json, python-3.x, parsing

I need to count the number of requests for each of the methods - GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, HEAD from Apache access.log.
An example of an entry from the access.log:

```
83.167.113.100 - - [12/Dec/2015:18:31:25 +0100] "POST /administrator/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 4494 "http://almhuette-raith.at/administrator/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0" 8566
```

And here is the code:

```
    regul_ip = (r"^(?P<ips>.*?)")
    regul_method = (r"\"(?P<request_method>GET|POST|PUT|DELETE|HEAD)")

    dict_m = defaultdict(lambda: {"GET": 0, "POST": 0, "PUT": 0, "DELETE": 0, "HEAD": 0})
    with open(args.logfile) as file:
         for index, line in enumerate(file.readlines()):
            try:
                  ip = re.search(reg_ip, line).group()
                  method = re.search(reg_meth, line).groups()[0]
            except AttributeError:
                  pass
            dict_m[ip][method] += 1
    print(json.dumps(dict_m, indent=4))
```

The output is:

```
  },
    "107.173.213.131": {
        "GET": 1,
        "POST": 0,
        "PUT": 0,
        "DELETE": 0,
        "HEAD": 0
    },
    "5.152.203.98": {
        "GET": 1,
        "POST": 0,
        "PUT": 0,
        "DELETE": 0,
        "POST": 3,
        "PUT": 0,
        "DELETE": 0,
        "HEAD": 0
    },
    "5.141.199.97": {
        "GET": 9,
        "POST": 9,
        "PUT": 0,
        "DELETE":
```

But I need the following:

```
{
    "GET": 2248007,
    "POST": 918924,
    "PUT": 75,
    "DELETE": 1,
    "HEAD": 49973
}
```

How can I fix the code?

Comment: Can't you simply count the number of occurrences of each of these words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the log file, each request will have keyword (POST, GET, DELETE, PUT) once. So you can simply count the occurrences of each keyword.

```
dict_m = dict()    
with open(args.logfile) as file:
    data = file.read()
    dict_m["GET"] = data.count("GET")
    dict_m["POST"] = data.count("POST")
    dict_m["DELETE"] = data.count("DELETE")
    dict_m["PUT"] = data.count("PUT")
```